# When importing unity .fbx models to blender, the armature becomes disproportional and oversized

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

I have a unity character model in the `.fbx` format. I'm trying to import it to blender in order to create some animations. Upon importing, the armature for the model gets distorted with some bones becoming 4 or 5 times the normal size. Why is this happening? And how do I fix this?

[image: Picture showing oversized armature]

Answer (score 0):

For animation, I always make my own rigs. I too have bad experience importing .fbx files from unity into blender.

So at this point, I don't think there is an easy way to import a mesh + rig from unity to  blender. I advise you to make your own rig for the character. Just because you understand your own rig way better (this is a plus for weight painting & bone movement / animation)

Also when creating a rig for unity it has to be done in a special way because if you want to use Unity's blend tree you should go for making a "Humanoid Rig", There are a couple of decent tutorials on youtube for this just search for

> Blender to unity humanoid rig

When exporting Animations I would suggest [looking at the answer of this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163522/blender-to-unity-animations-are-exporting-2x) I made a while back. So you dont get any double animations and such

If there is a way to easily import a character + rig from unity into blender, I would also love to know :)

Good luck with your project!